# AVD with custom userdata.img doesn't boot

Tags: mount, avd-manager

I have been trying to emulate a real android device using AVD by replacing the sdcard (sdcard.img) and userdata (userdata.img) pulled from my device.

> Xiaomi Redmi 1S
>   Android 4.4.2

Only replacing the sdcard causes no problems. However, after replacing the userdata (even with a stock sdcard), the AVD fails to mount the `/data` partition (according to the kernel logs (`-show-kernel`), as a result of which the AVD never boots.
The userdata image is quite big (5.9G), and I have used a sufficient partition size (with `-partition-size 7168`).
Pulling (with `adb pull`) `/dev/block/mtdblock1` (which is supposed to be mounted as `/data`) from the live AVD shows that it is actually an empty file (therefore running `e2fsck` with alternate superblocks has no effect).
However, `e2fsck` identifies `userdata.img` as clean, and `file userdata.img` says that it is a valid ext4 filesystem. In addition, I have mounted and found `userdata.img` to be a valid partition.

```
EXT4-fs (mtdblock0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: barrier=1
end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock1, sector 2  
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): unable to read superblock  
fs_mgr: Running /system/bin/e2fsck on /dev/block/mtdblock1  
e2fsck: e2fsck 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)  
e2fsck: /system/bin/e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/block/mtdblock1
e2fsck:  
e2fsck: The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2  
e2fsck: filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2  
e2fsck: filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock  
e2fsck: is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:  
e2fsck:     e2fsck -b 8193 <device>  
e2fsck:   
e2fsck: e2fsck terminated by exit(8)    
end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock1, sector 2  
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): unable to read superblock  
fs_mgr: Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/mtdblock1 at /data  
init: fs_mgr_mount_all returned an error
```